# Multiple Edit Forms for Multiple List Views

Tags: 2007

We have a list application that has many customized list views. We need to be able to call a specific customized edit form for a specific custom list view. For instance, the Pre Awarded Funding view needs to call a specific edit form that displays only fields appropriate for the funding people to deal with. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Have you achieved this ? I also need to show customised display forms for different users. I would like to know if multiple views are possible or not? If you got a solution, it will be great if you could share that. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can't really tie a specific for to a specif view to my knowledge, you have to provide links to the customized forms.  Typically in these cases I create a user dashboard and hardwire in links to various forms using conditional formatting in a dataview web part.  Based on the status, you can provide the appropriate URL to your custom form depending on what you want the user to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SharePoint Designer 2010.  Open your site, create or edit a list, go to the Forms Section and click "New..."  Specify the new form to be an "Edit" form.  That new form will now be in the list.  Select that new form and edit the form view.  You can add/remove elements to the view at will using the designer.

Comment: Actually, I've done customized form editing for the standard forms associated with the list. What I need to know how to do is tie a specific form to a specific list view. There may be several versions of the forms customized to work with a particular list. Changing the standard forms listed in the properties of the list in SharePoint Designer is short of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would think about doing is introducing Content Types.  So in the case of a view let say you have view a.  Set up a content type that just has those fields you are interested in.  You now have specific fields that mimic what you see on a view.  You then can go ahead and modify the form experience in SP designer for that content type you just created.

Might be wrong approach but just a thought.

Comment: I thought about content types first too.. but I think it won't work since the item's content type applies to all views / forms.